Springboot - Authentication Service
I am developing a Web application using Spring boot (I am a beginner). How can I make my code better?
This code is from "AuthenticationService.java".
I first made an interface for defining all methods, and then I implemented that interface in this AuthenticationService class.
package com.discwords.discwords.service;


import com.discwords.discwords.model.*;
import com.discwords.discwords.repository.ProfileRepo;
import com.discwords.discwords.repository.SessionRepo;
import com.discwords.discwords.repository.UserRepo;
import com.discwords.discwords.repository.UserSecretRepo;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCrypt;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class AuthorizationServiceImpl implements AuthorizationService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @Autowired
    private UserSecretRepo userSecretRepo;

    @Autowired
    private SessionRepo sessionRepo;


    @Autowired
    private ProfileRepo profileRepo;

    @Autowired
    JWTService jwtService;

    @Value("${google_client_id}")
    private String CLIENT_ID;


    @Override
    public UserSessionDTO loginUser(UserDTO user) {
        Optional<User> userRes = userRepo.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
        if (userRes.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("User not found");
            return null;
        }

        User existingUser = userRes.get();

        Optional<Profile> profileRes = profileRepo.findByUserId(existingUser.getUserId());
        if(profileRes.isEmpty()){
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "No Profile with this user id");
        }
        Profile profile = profileRes.get();

        Optional<UserSession> userSessionRes = sessionRepo.findByUserId(existingUser.getUserId());
        if (userSessionRes.isPresent()) {
            UserSession userSession = userSessionRes.get();
            if (userSession.getSessionEndTime().before(new Date())) {
                System.out.println("Deleting User session for new");
                sessionRepo.delete(userSession);
            } else {
                System.out.println("User already logged in");
                return new UserSessionDTO(profile, userSession.getToken());
            }
        }

        Optional<UserSecret> userSecretRes = userSecretRepo.findById(existingUser.getUserId());

        if (userSecretRes.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("User secret is empty");
            return null;
        }

        UserSecret userSecret = userSecretRes.get();

        if (BCrypt.checkpw(user.getPassword(), userSecret.getPassword())) {
            String jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(existingUser.getEmail(), Long.toString(existingUser.getUserId()));
            int newSessionId = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 100000);
            UserSession newUserSession = new UserSession(
                    existingUser.getUserId(),
                    jwtToken,
                    new Date(),
                    jwtService.extractExpiryDate(jwtToken),
                    newSessionId
            );

            UserSession userSession = sessionRepo.save(newUserSession);
            UserSessionDTO userSessionDTO = new UserSessionDTO(profile, userSession.getToken());

            return userSessionDTO;

        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public UserSessionDTO signupUser(UserDTO user) {

//        checking if email already exists
        Optional<User> userRes = userRepo.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
        if (!userRes.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.CONFLICT, "User already exist");
        }

//       checking if username already exists
        Optional<User> tempUserRes = userRepo.findByUsername(user.getUsername());
        if (!tempUserRes.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.CONFLICT, "Username exist");
        }


        String password = BCrypt.hashpw(user.getPassword(), BCrypt.gensalt());
        Long userId = generateId();

        User newUser = new User(userId, user.getEmail(), user.getUsername());
        userRepo.save(newUser);

        UserSecret newUserSecret = new UserSecret(userId, password);
        userSecretRepo.save(newUserSecret);


        //creating profile
        Profile profile = new Profile();
        profile.setUserId(newUser.getUserId());
        profile.setEmail(newUser.getEmail());
        System.out.println(newUser.getUsername());
        profile.setUsername(newUser.getUsername());
        profileRepo.save(profile);



        //token generation

        String jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(newUser.getEmail(), Long.toString(newUser.getUserId()));

        int newSessionId = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 100000);
        UserSession newUserSession = new UserSession(
                newUser.getUserId(),
                jwtToken,
                new Date(),
                jwtService.extractExpiryDate(jwtToken),
                newSessionId
        );
        UserSession userSession = sessionRepo.save(newUserSession);


        UserSessionDTO userSessionDTO = new UserSessionDTO(profile, userSession.getToken());

        return userSessionDTO;
    }

    @Override
    public UserSessionDTO signupUserWithGoogle(TokenRequestDTO tokenRequestDTO) throws Exception {

        GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance())
                .setAudience(Collections.singletonList(CLIENT_ID)).build();
        GoogleIdToken idToken = verifier.verify(tokenRequestDTO.getTokenId());

        if (idToken != null) {
            GoogleIdToken.Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();

            String userEmail = payload.getEmail();

            Optional<User> userRes = userRepo.findByEmail(userEmail);

            if (userRes.isPresent()) {
                return loginUserWithGoogle(tokenRequestDTO);
            }

            long userId = generateId();
            String username = userEmail.split("@")[0];

            User newUser = new User(userId, userEmail, username);
            userRepo.save(newUser);

            Profile profile = new Profile();
            profile.setUserId(newUser.getUserId());
            profile.setEmail(newUser.getEmail());
            System.out.println(newUser.getUsername());
            profile.setUsername(newUser.getUsername());
            profileRepo.save(profile);


            String jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(newUser.getEmail(), Long.toString(newUser.getUserId()));
            int newSessionId = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 100000);
            UserSession newUserSession = new UserSession(
                    newUser.getUserId(),
                    jwtToken,
                    new Date(),
                    jwtService.extractExpiryDate(jwtToken),
                    newSessionId
            );

            UserSession userSession = sessionRepo.save(newUserSession);

            UserSessionDTO userSessionDTO = new UserSessionDTO(profile, userSession.getToken());

            return userSessionDTO;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public UserSessionDTO loginUserWithGoogle(TokenRequestDTO tokenRequestDTO) throws Exception {

        GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance())
                .setAudience(Collections.singletonList(CLIENT_ID)).build();
        GoogleIdToken idToken = verifier.verify(tokenRequestDTO.getTokenId());

        if (idToken != null) {
            GoogleIdToken.Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();

            String userEmail = payload.getEmail();

            Optional<User> userRes = userRepo.findByEmail(userEmail);

            if (userRes.isEmpty()) {
                return signupUserWithGoogle(tokenRequestDTO);
            }

            User existingUser = userRes.get();

            Optional<Profile> profileRes = profileRepo.findByUserId(existingUser.getUserId());
            if(profileRes.isEmpty()){
                throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "No Profile with this user id");
            }
            Profile profile = profileRes.get();


            Optional<UserSession> userSessionRes = sessionRepo.findByUserId(existingUser.getUserId());
            if (userSessionRes.isPresent()) {
                UserSession userSession = userSessionRes.get();
                if (userSession.getSessionEndTime().before(new Date())) {
                    sessionRepo.delete(userSession);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("User already logged in");
                    return new UserSessionDTO(profile, userSession.getToken());
                }
            } else {
                String jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(existingUser.getEmail(), Long.toString(existingUser.getUserId()));
                int newSessionId = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 100000);
                UserSession newUserSession = new UserSession(
                        existingUser.getUserId(),
                        jwtToken,
                        new Date(),
                        jwtService.extractExpiryDate(jwtToken),
                        newSessionId
                );
                UserSession userSession = sessionRepo.save(newUserSession);

                UserSessionDTO userSessionDTO = new UserSessionDTO(profile, userSession.getToken());

                return userSessionDTO;

            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    //using token
    @Override
    public boolean authorizeUser(String jwtToken) throws Exception {

        long userId = (long) jwtService.extractUserId(jwtToken);
        Date tokenExpiryDate = (Date) jwtService.extractExpiryDate(jwtToken);
        Optional<UserSession> userSessionRes = sessionRepo.findByUserId(userId);

        if(userSessionRes.isEmpty()){
            return false;
        }

        UserSession userSession = userSessionRes.get();

        if(userSession.getSessionEndTime().before(new Date()) || tokenExpiryDate.before(new Date())){
            sessionRepo.delete(userSession);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }


    //TODO - Making Util package for all these stuff
    private Long generateId() {
        Long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        time = time % 1000000000;
        time = time * 1000;
        time = time + (long) (Math.random() * 1000);

        return time;
    }

}



Welcome to Code Review! Is the term "fresher" a synonym for beginner? If it is meant to signify something else then feel free to edit the post.

@SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ By "Fresher " I mean I never worked with any Industrial project or Company. I have been coding since 5-6 years for my own projects (I do no know why I still write s*itty code) as student and now I completed my graduation as CSE engineering (lol). But if you think "Beginner" is still right word then yeah leave it as it is. Btw Thank you for your help.

For a "fresher" it looks pretty good so far. Good method names, exception handling, and overall design choice.
The first thing improvement I noticed was some code was duplicated and could be reduced.
private UserSessionDTO handleUserSession(User existingUser, Profile profile) {
    if (existingUser == null) {
        // Handle the case where existingUser is null
        return null; // or throw an appropriate exception
    }

    Optional<UserSession> userSessionRes = sessionRepo.findByUserId(existingUser.getUserId());
    
    if (userSessionRes.isPresent()) {
        UserSession userSession = userSessionRes.get();
        if (userSession.getSessionEndTime().before(new Date())) {
            sessionRepo.delete(userSession);
        } else {
            return new UserSessionDTO(profile, userSession.getToken());
        }
    }
    
    return null;
}

Some of the logic could also be moved into utility classes, especially good if it can be used elsewhere.
public class IdUtils {
    public static Long generateId() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() % 1_000_000_000 * 1_000 + (long)(Math.random() * 1_000);
    }
}

In my projects I personally use custom exceptions for more clarity in debugging and logging.
public class UserNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    public UserNotFoundException(String email) {
        super("User not found with email: " + email);
    }
}

You can then throw this exception in your methods:
if (userRes.isEmpty()) {
    throw new UserNotFoundException(user.getEmail());
}

That being said I would be leveraging a logging framework (SLF4J, Log4j, etc..) instead of System.out. For small personal development projects I'm guilty of using System.out but I feel like it's best practice to get used to logging regularly.
if (userRes.isEmpty()) {
    throw new UserNotFoundException(user.getEmail());
}

Your use of the optional property could also be problematic in certain scenarios. orElseThrow or map is generally considered safer and cleaner.
User existingUser = userRepo.findByEmail(user.getEmail()).orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(user.getEmail()))

Another example of a problematic use of Optional:
Optional<User> userOptional = userRepo.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
if (userOptional.isPresent()) {
    User user = userOptional.get();  // At this point, we're sure the user exists.
    // Additional logic here
} else {
    // Handle case where user is not found
}

In this example, we check if the Optional contains a value and then call .get(). However, if you forget to check for presence and directly call .get(), you’ll run into a NoSuchElementException.
Here’s the cleaner approach using orElseThrow() which avoids that:
User user = userRepo.findByEmail(user.getEmail())
        .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(user.getEmail()));

This way, if the Optional is empty, it automatically throws a custom exception. It's cleaner and more expressive.
Another example is that I've also had problems using nested optionals.
Optional<Profile> profileOptional = profileRepo.findByUserId(existingUser.getUserId());
if (profileOptional.isPresent()) {
    Profile profile = profileOptional.get();
    // ... do something with the profile
}

Instead, you could flatten this using ifPresent() or map():
profileRepo.findByUserId(existingUser.getUserId())
    .ifPresent(profile -> {
        // Handle found profile
    });

or with map() for chaining:
User user = userRepo.findByEmail(user.getEmail())
        .map(existingUser -> {
            return profileRepo.findByUserId(existingUser.getUserId())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ProfileNotFoundException(existingUser.getUserId()));
        })
        .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(user.getEmail()));


Welcome to Code Review! Nice answer. A couple remarks. Method handleUserSession() will blow up with NoSuchElementException if optional is empty. And it's generally considered an antipattern to use Optional as a parameter because the caller misses an opportunity to make a fluent call via Optional.map() and we're tossing around a potentially empty optional. I would suggest changing parameter type to User.

And since variable userRes (of type optional) is basically redundant, the last line in your answer might be written as : User existingUser = userRepo.findByEmail(user.getEmail()).orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(user.getEmail()));

Hey, Thank you for your suggestions. I was thinking about logging stuffs instead of using System.out. And about "Optional" property, I saw people using it on some github projects, so please can you tell me by any example how will it be problematic? I am really looking forward for your more suggestions. Thank you again.

SRP violation
Low-level logic for creating and persisting sessions, creating Profiles, generating IDs does not belong to this Service.
Spring Security
Consider introducing Spring Security project into your application instead of doing things like managing sessions and implementing OIDC manually.
Constructor Injection
It's recommended practice to use constructor-based dependency injection instead of applying of @Autowired on fields.
Constructor makes all required dependencies explicit and guarantees the constructed instance will be fully initialed. This approach follows the spirit of OOP. While field injection breaks the encapsulation and opens the dour to creation of non-initialized instances.
It's less noisy than field injection. If the class defines only one constructor, then no annotations required (otherwise, you need to tell which one Spring should use by annotating it with @Autowired).
And with constructor injection, you can make fields final.

Field injection is only suitable for test classes, but not in production code.
Don't use java.util.Date
This class is legacy, and it's still there only for backward compatibility reasons.
With the inception of Java 8 all legacy date-time classes were superseded by types from the java.time package.
In this case, a better option will be to use java.time.Instant which represent a specific moment on the timeline in UTC.
Use ControllerAdvice
Don't return null. Don't propagate the problem, forcing the caller to perform null-checks.
If it's not possible to return a meaningful value from a method, throw an Exception.
Use ControllerAdvice to define a global exception-handling mechanism and generate appropriate HTTP-responses based on the exception type and supplementary data which you can embed into your application-specific exception.

Hey, Thank you for your awesome advice. About generating Ids, I was about create a separate util package. But where should I move these "creating profiles and sessions" ?? Should I just add these into Util package ? Because I do not really know where to put them. I am looking forward for your suggestions. Thank you!

Btw, I am aware of Spring Security but I didn't use it because I do not really know how it works. Tutorials online just ask to use some magical methods which do some stuffs.

"Field injection is only suitable for test classes, but not in production code." - So should I use "Constructor Injection" for production code?

" should I use "Constructor Injection" for production code" - absolutely yes, providing dependencies through constructor is a recommended practice.

"where should I move these "creating profiles and sessions"" - create separate abstractions. Here's a design mantra: identify responsibilities in your business logic, introduce an abstraction for each responsibility encapsulating all logic that pertains to it and exposes clear easy to use hi-level methods. This approach reduces duplication, makes code easier to test (since you delineated responsibilities) and more maintainable. In this case, managing sessions warrants a separate service, same for profiles.

"About generating Ids, I was about create a separate util package." - it's better to separate util classes from the application core because they are faceless, not tied to specific use cases. And be very judicious about what you put in there, avoid "everything is util" mindset.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
